# How to define a struct having inheritance in header file?

Tags: c++, struct, header

I have a struct in my cpp file that contains a colon definition:

```
struct GeomMeshLoader: VRayStaticGeomSource, VRaySceneModifierInterface
{
   <definitions>
}
```

How should I define this struct in a header file ?
If I simply do:

```
struct GeomMeshLoader;
```

then I will get during compilation of another cpp file including this header:

```
allocation of incomplete type 'GeomMeshLoader'
```

If I declare the header like:

```
struct GeomMeshLoader: VRayStaticGeomSource, VRaySceneModifierInterface;
```

then it will fail at compilation with:

```
error: expected '{' after base class list
```

What is the way to put in headers struct definitions containing colons ?

Comment: Colon definition? Dude, it's called inheritance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
allocation of incomplete type 'GeomMeshLoader'
```

means you have some code that tries to use that type in some way that needs to see the full definition (i.e. not just holding a pointer or reference). How can it allocate an object of that type if it can't work out the object's size? For which it needs to see the whole class: all the base classes, all the member data.

You will need to put the whole class definition in the header. You can't forward declare it and have the definition in the `.cpp`.

The *definition* of any member functions (but not member function templates) can still be in the `.cpp`. *Declarations* of those member functions must go in the class definition (in the header).

So:

```
// geomeshloader.h
#ifndef INCLUDED_GEOMESHLOADER_H // Don't forget your header guards
#define INCLUDED_GEOMESHLOADER_H
struct GeomMeshLoader: VRayStaticGeomSource, VRaySceneModifierInterface {
    int i_;
    void foo() const;
};
#endif
```

and

```
// geomeshloader.cpp
#include "geomeshloader.h"
void GeoMeshLoader::foo() const
{
    // do stuff
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but when I put the whole struct definition in the header (which is included by multiple cpp's), I get a duplicate object error when linking. How can I then prevent this ?

Comment: [Header guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) stop your definition being copied in multiple times into a single translation unit (i.e. being seen more than once in one `.cpp` file).